# Most efficient way to render HTML and PHP

Tags: php, optimization

What is the most efficient way to render a page with PHP and HTML?

Concatenating

```
$html = '<span><img src="page.png" alt="page" />'.$variable1.'</span>';
echo $html
```

Replacing variables

```
$html = "<span><img src=\"page.png\" alt=\"page\" />{$variable1}</span>";
echo $html;
```

Inline PHP tags - This doesn't seem practical even if it is the most efficient on a large scale

```
<span><img src="page.png" alt="page" /><?php echo $variable1; ?></span>
```

Please assume you are generate a whole page.  I used the snippets above as an example of each method.

Thanks!

Comment: There's also `echo '<span><img src="page.png" alt="page" />',$variable1,'</span>';` way (note `,` instead of `.` concatenation) The `,` just outputs one after another.

Comment: I find weird that this question has been closed as "not constructive" as it could be answered with "..acts, references, or expertise..." and in fact to "...solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion..." would be a necessary aspect of finding the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the goal you try to achieve.

If it's just rendering a simple page, the most efficient way is to concatenate code using single quote (based on benchmark) (even if the difference is not so important).

But I'm guessing you are building a website, and you will use html+php widely. If so, I recommend you to use a template engine, or, directly PHP.

Using any template engine will reduce the performance, of course, but it will improve the readability of your project and structure it in a better way. The ratio "lost performance"/"readability - maintain" is worth it. You should go for it (again, if you plan to render many html pages). See [MVC Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Now, for the template engine, I would recommend you to use PHP directly since it has first been developed for this purpose. You can find many template engines that just finally use php in the templates, and the same apply for Frameworks. If you take a look at [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) for example, you'll see that the templates are made of php.

Now, for security reasons, using PHP in your template greatly depends on who is going to edit templates. If it's only you, or someone you have a total trust, you should go for it. If your users will be able to edit the templates (for any kind of reasons), then I absolutely should avoid it, because they can do whatever they want on your server, including hitting the database, viewing all the files (even configurations ones) etc.

Comment: What is template engine?

Comment: I'm not sure if you don't understand the global definition or you want a more precise one. You should refer to the definition given by wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)

Comment: Ok I have got it that template engine means one which represents data or data models in different ways. But with respect to PHP, to what can we say template engine? Is it the "view" in MVC pattern or something else?\

Comment: MVC is independant of PHP. MVC is a design pattern that is used by many web frameworks. A template will be the V(iew) of the MVC pattern. A template engine, will take the data received from the C(ontroller) and give them to the V(iew) with a special formatting (like {$var}, @var, <?= echo $var; ?>, depending on which template engine you use).

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough performance difference to matter or measure. Do the most readable thing. In my (many) PHP apps I mostly use embedded PHP substitutions with short tags:

```
<p><?= $text ?></p>
```

Comment: Its discouraged to use shortags because some hosts/servers disable it afaik.

Comment: Short tags are always available as of PHP 5.4, regardless of server settings. http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0

Comment: If you control your own web server and its settings this isn't an issue. If your ISP disables short tags for some reason (I've never seen one that does) you can either switch ISPs or use your text editor to find/replace the short tags to turn them into long tags. Short tags are really a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is: readable and maintainable.

That being said I'd probably use a template engine (like [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)), but if not available I definitly go for inline php tags (as used in views in Zend Framework views and Symfony success templates).

If I had to generate html inside php, I'd go for `sprinft('<img src="%s">", $src');` or concatination.

I really, really dislike the use of `{$var}` or `$html = "$var"`.

Comment: See http://www.phpbench.com/ ... depending on page size and hits it's microoptimization anyway.

Comment: That's exactly why I vote for performance, but for 'readable and maintainable'. As the start of my post states.